# Proper way to manually install a python library [osx-mavericks]

Tags: python, osx-mavericks

I'm trying to install a Python library (https://github.com/haakondr/graph-edit-distance-python) on my system. The issue is that the distribution is lacking a setup.py file. In this kind of situations, what is the proper way to install a Python library on osx?

Comment: Since it's a pure Python package, you should be able to manually install it by unzipping the contents of the gethub zip archive file into your `<python install path>/lib/site-packages` folder. It might be a good idea to first do that into some other folder and test it out beforehand. Unfortunately the distribution also doesn't include a test suite either -- although there's a file called `edit_dist.py` in the root folder that looks like it could be used to do a sanity check.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't actually just an issue on OSX. This would be true anywhere you wanted to use this

The short answer is you don't actually need to install it.

You can just treat it as a set of files. If you download the .zip file from GitHub or clone the repo --- either way --- you can then access it directly.

Note that in doing that, you'll have to install all the dependencies and what not yourself.